# How to get the machine network IO in bytes per second?

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring

I'm trying to figure out the network usage for a given EC2 machine (linux os) in "bytes per second".

At first I was using `TcpInsegs`, `TcpOutsegs`, `UdpInDatagrams` and `UdpOutDatagrams`, retrieved from `/proc/net/netstat/` and `/proc/net/snmp`. But I soon realized that these metrics are of unit "count per second".

I need "bytes per second" because the network capacity information I'm given is in this unit. Is there anyway to get this information instead?

I'm aware of the two metrics `IpExtInOctets` and `IpExtOutOctets` but did not know if they are the right metrics for me. And I did not find the documentation for them.

Anyone knows how I can get the machine network IO in bytes per second? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SNMP, under the interfaces table, you can get both (total packets, and total bytes) input and output per interface, so you don't have to add the individual to get the total.

Apart of this, all the counters `TcpInSegs`, `TcpOutSegs`, etc. are complemented by the same number of coutners, but in bytes (they are suffixed `octets`, instead, but meaning the same.)  The problem you don't find them is a nomenclature one.  In SNMP jargon, bytes are called octets, TCP packets are called segments, UDP are called datagrams, and in ethernet they are called packets (not sure of this last point).

That info is stored in linux in the file `/proc/net/dev` with the following format:

```
$ cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
enp2s0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
wlp3s0:  164083     571    0    0    0     0          0         0    16635      98    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo:     660      10    0    0    0     0          0         0      660      10    0    0    0     0       0          0
$ _
```

will probably suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to make sure: (1) The interfaces table you mentioned was the file `/proc/net/dev` right? (2) In `/proc/net/netstat` and `/proc/net/snmp` files, I only find metrics that are suffixed with `octets` under `IpExt` section, for example `IpExtInOctets` and `IpExtOutOctets`. Am I checking the wrong files? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know where linux maintains all those variables (I don't have a linux machine now here to check) I know this from SNMP, probably the best thing you can do it to install an snmp agent in your machine and ask it for values with `snmpget(1)` or `snmpwalk(1)`.  As those utilities are designed long ago, they conserver a fixed output format, and you'll be far more pottable, asking not only your own values, but other machines also.  Anyway, if I find a linux box, I'll chet its `/proc` to see where does it maintain the numbers.

Comment: `IpExtInOctets` supposedly are the `extra` octets not included in the other counters.  You need to read a little on SNMP to get rid on how the counters operate.  Just I'll try to get a linux box and give you some light on this... wait a little.

Comment: The information you want is stored in `/proc/net/dev` file.  you have the columns divided in three groups: the first is the interface name, then the input (receive) data, followed by the transmitted data.... on each group you have bytes, packets, errors, dropped, etc.
The information is per netword device  and doesn't relate to tcp, upd or other IP protocols, but at the interface level.

Comment: Oh got it thanks! Interface level data will be even more convenient for me.

Comment: I have edited the answer to show the format and everything.